# How to manage Interactions among Visuals in two different dash boards in Power Bi?

Tags: powerbi-desktop

I have a bar chart like this :

[image]

For privacy Reasons I had to obscure labels. So let's call them Label 1 Label 2 etc. If I click on one of them I want to have returned the relative rows in this matrix, that is placed in another dashboards (the second page of my report) :

[image]

If I put this table on the same page of the report I do not get any problem. But if I put this table on another page of my report nothing is happening. I read already some reports about synchronization but I still have some issues.

Comment: can you not just directly show record. {Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-see-data-see-records) for Ref

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Solved. Being relatively new to Power BI it was not clear what I was searching for. I solved by  drill-through. I just chosen the page to drill out putting on the drill-through space on the right side of the page the set of variable of interest.

I found [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/power-bi/desktop-drillthrough)  and this [you-tube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GaY3_zrj21U) to be very helpful